# Understanding the idea of space of test functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I was learning the functional analysis course and came across the idea of test functions:

let $\Omega \subset R^n$ be an open set. For each compact subset $K \subset int\, \Omega$,

$C^∞_0(K):\{u\in C^∞_0(Ω):supp\,u\subset K\} $

Introducing a sequence of seminorms:
$p_n(u)=sup\{ |D^\alpha u(x)|:x \in K, |\alpha|=n\}$
we equip $C^∞_0(K)$ with this locally convex topology. With this topology the space is frequently called the space of test functions with supports in K, denoted as $D(K)$

Let $\mathscr B_k$ denote a corresponding base of convex, balanced, absorbing neighborhoods for zero function. Consider now the family $\mathscr B$ of all nonempty, convex, balanced sets $W$ from $C^∞_0(K)$ such that $\forall \: compact\:K\subset\Omega, \:\:\exists V \in \mathscr B_k: V\subset W \cap C^∞_0(K)$

There are two propositions:

- $\mathscr B$ is a base of this locally convex topology on $C^∞_0(\Omega)$
  **My question:** Does this proposition mean that every base (defined as above) of this $C^∞_0(K)$ will have to intesect with the neighborhood of the zero function? I can't imagine why this has to be the case. A simple explanation will be appreciated.
- Let $\phi_n$  be a sequence of functions from this space of test functions $D(\Omega)$. The following are equivalent to each other:
  (1) If $supp\,u\subset K$ and for any multi-index $\alpha$, $D^\alpha \phi_n \to0$ uniformly in K.
  (2) $\phi_n \to 0$ in $D(\Omega)$.
  **My question:** I find a proof of this, but I want to understand this more intuitively. Does this proposition mean that for any $C^∞_0$ functions with compact support, the vanishing of its any derivatives indicates that the functions themselves will also vanish on K (and vice versa)? Can I understand this (just intuitively) as : Since the two ends of the compact support functions are fixed at zero outside K, so when derivative converges to $0$ on K, it means the functions can't have a big change on K, which is why $\phi_n \to 0$?

Thank you! (Further searching test functions online involves something with Distribution theory and unfortunately as an undergrad I haven't touched any of this theory.)

Comment: Is $W$ supposed to be from $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$? From what space is $\mathscr B_k$?

Comment: @supinf Yea, B or W is from this space of test function D. Which is $C_0^ ∞ $ as well as having the sup norm topology.